# Crystal Report font parameter

Tags: fonts, parameters, crystal-reports, report

Is it possible to create a parameter within a crystal report that will allow you to select a font from a drop down list, and when running the report the text will display in the font selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can create with the help formula.

1st create a static parameter with your font value (Type:Number)

[image]

Tie this parameter to a non matching attribute.

2nd select all your reporting attribute and right click `Format Objects..` -->go to font.

[image]

Place the parameter inside the formula editor.

[image]